# How to Transfer Ownership of an iOS App with in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes, app-transfer

A month ago, we have implemented subscription model of in-app purchases in our application. now we want to transfer it to another Organization account. so Is there any way to transfer an app including previously-removed In-App Purchase subscriptions?

We have noticed, that app can’t be transferred due subscriptions in it. How can we solve this problem?

Find the attach screenshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate you help.

Comment: Have you created the app-specific shared secret (which should be shared with the Buyer)?

Comment: Thanks your response but I can not Generate app-specific secret. I got following error " We can't process your request.Try reloading the page. If the problem persists, contact us."

Comment: I too am in the same case. In the WWDC, they announced IAP App Transfer on a slide, but couldn't find more information about it.